# If $f\cdot g$ is continuous at $x=a$, then are $f$ and $g$ both continuous at $x=a$?

Tags: calculus, continuity

I'll state the question from my textbook below:

> State whether the below statement is true or false:
>
> If $f\cdot g$ is  continuous at $x=a$, then $f$ and $g$ are both continuous at $x=a$.

The textbook says that it is false.

I tried thinking of a very basic example considering $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = \frac 1x$. But then I recalled that $p(x) = \frac xx$ and $q(x) = 1$ are different functions. So, it didn't work as a counter example.

So, can someone please provide a counter example? Or is the statement true, just as I think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is false. As example You can take $f=x$, $g=\theta(x)$ (Heaviside function)

Answer (score 3):

Take $f = 1_{[a,\infty)}$ and $g = 1_{(-\infty,a)}$. Then $fg = 0$, but none are continuous at $a$.

Comment: What does the subscript after $1$ denote?

Comment: @SamInuyashaANMF The function $1_{[a, b]}$ refers to the function which is equal to $1$ in $[a, b]$, and $0$ elsewhere.